# boto3 mturk: smiley causes An error occurred (ParameterValidationError) when calling the CreateHITWithHITType operation

Tags: python-3.x, boto3

Using Python 3.7 and boto3 to create HITs on MTurk, the boto3 library crashes with the following error. I did some testing and concluded that the error is caused by the "" character in the `HITLayoutParameters` field (see below).

How can I avoid this issue while still uploading the text in its original form?

```
hit_layout_id = 'XXXXM4PUG5TWD3TK4NDUWHRJUUXXXX'
hit_layout_params = [{'Name': 'text', 'Value': 'Listening and learning, but standing strong  pic.twitter.com/7TSroSf8h1 — Ilhan Omar (@IlhanMN) February 11, 2019\n<u><b>Omar</b></u> did not apologize, however, for another anti-Semitic comment she made in February, accusing pro-Israel Americans of having an “allegiance to a foreign country.”'}, {'Name': 'target', 'Value': 'Omar'}]
hit_type_id = 'XXXX7R2NRGZ96BC693FAIJ5481XXXX'
lifetime_in_seconds = 259200
num_max_assignments = 5

# boto3 client initialization
client = ...

# upload the hit
client.create_hit_with_hit_type(
    HITTypeId=hit_type_id,
    MaxAssignments=num_max_assignments,
    LifetimeInSeconds=lifetime_in_seconds,
    RequesterAnnotation=requester_annotation,
    HITLayoutId=hit_layout_id,
    HITLayoutParameters=hit_layout_params,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's an encoding issue.
It is possible in your app to encode you text to the supported encoding and decode it when you're going to use it?